# Returning different classes (like separate pages) into one container

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

I want to use the container on the right as my main view (call different widgets from other class files). And use the one on the left container as my navigation bar. So if someone presses the first button - instead of this bird image I want to call form which is in other files class.

I need some kind of live variable, but have no clue of what to do.

This is my code for that bird.

```
 child: logo()
```

Here I return another class called logo, if I press first nav bar link I want to return another class instead of this bird.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need a variable to hold the current item, and when that menu option is selected you must refresh the state (using setState or any state management) in order to update your details view.

I prepared a basic example for you:

Result

[image]

Code:

```dart
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeWidget> createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
// Replace these containers with the widgets you want
  final items = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    ),
  ];

  late Widget _widgetSelected = items.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return MyMenuItemWidget(
                  text: 'My Item ${index + 1}',
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _widgetSelected = items[index];
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: MyDetailWidget(
            child: _widgetSelected,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyMenuItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMenuItemWidget({
    required this.text,
    required this.onPressed,
    super.key,
  });
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDetailWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDetailWidget({
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            blurRadius: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. I think it might be my solution. Anyway I see you have some good skills, if you text me on whatsapp +353874444151 I might need more of your help, I could pay you also for teaching me. Text me please :)

Comment: You can mark this answer as solved :)